# Push onto a dereferenced array gives warning

Tags: perl

I have the code:

```
push @$args{"ARRAY"}, "value";
```

This gives warning saying:

```
push on reference is experimental at ...
```

If I just use block around the array:

```
push @{args{"ARRAY"}}, "value";
```

Then the warning disappears. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@$args{"ARRAY"}` is equivalent to `@{$args}{"ARRAY"}`, not `@{$args{"ARRAY"}}`. From [`perlref`, section "Using References"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References):

> Because of being able to omit the curlies for the simple case of `$$x`,
>       people often make the mistake of viewing the dereferencing symbols as
>       proper operators, and wonder about their precedence. If they were,
>       though, you could use parentheses instead of braces. That's not the
>       case. Consider the difference below; case 0 is a short-hand version of
>       case 1, not case 2:
>
> ```
>    $$hashref{"KEY"}   = "VALUE";       # CASE 0
>    ${$hashref}{"KEY"} = "VALUE";       # CASE 1
>    ${$hashref{"KEY"}} = "VALUE";       # CASE 2
>    ${$hashref->{"KEY"}} = "VALUE";     # CASE 3
> ```